Google scripts code to send each row of a Google sheet document in a seperate email
I am new to this (I have experience with VBA, but this is slightly different). I would like to ask for help in regards of the script below. I would like to send each row of from a Google sheet in a separate email per row. I define column names as variable to be able to structure the data in the html body.
I have tried to build a loop to go through the rows and send the designed email in each cycle until it reaches the last used row.
The email is sent, but there is "NaN" for the email subject and "[object Object]" is in the received email's body. I am also unsure if the loop is working correctly as i have received more emails then the number of rows used.
I would be grateful for any advise.
Thank you in advance!
Kind regards,
Peter
I am stuck at this level :(

CODE:
`

  //access Google Sheets
    var wb=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet=wb.getSheetByName("automail");

    // access the data in a variable
    var data=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
    var lastline = sheet.getLastRow();

    for (var i=1;i=lastline;i++){

    //define the data points as per the data
    var takidatum =data[i,1];
    var sorrend=data[i,2];
    var takarito=data[i,3];
    var lakaskod=data[i,4];
    var vendegszam=data[i,5];
    var befejezes=data[i,6];
    var erkezes=data[i,7];
    var munkajellege=data[i,8];
    var komment=data[i,9];
    var cim=data[i,10];
    var emeletajto=data[i,11];
    var kapukod=data[i,12];
    var kulcsdoboz=data[i,13];

    //mail to
    var adressee=['xy@gmail.com'];

    //create template object for dynamic HTML contstructing
    var htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email.html'); 

    //define html vars as per column name to make cell content available for html reference
    htmlTemplate.takidatum=takidatum;
    htmlTemplate.sorrend=sorrend;
    htmlTemplate.takarito=takarito;
    htmlTemplate.lakaskod=lakaskod;
    htmlTemplate.vendegszam=vendegszam;
    htmlTemplate.befejezes=befejezes;
    htmlTemplate.erkezes=erkezes;
    htmlTemplate.munkajellege=munkajellege;
    htmlTemplate.komment=komment;
    htmlTemplate.cim=cim;
    htmlTemplate.emeletajto=emeletajto;
    htmlTemplate.kapukod=kapukod;
    htmlTemplate.kulcsdoboz=kulcsdoboz;

    //evaluate the template and returns an html output object
    var htmlforemail=htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

    //send email
    //GmailApp.sendEmail(
    //adressee,
    //takidatum + lakaskod + takarito,
    //{htmlBody: htmlforemail});

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
  adressee,
  takidatum + lakaskod + takarito,
  {htmlBody: htmlforemail});

}
}


Email html:

`
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <UL>
      <li>Dátum : <?=takidatum?></li>
      <li>Lakáskód : <?=lakaskod?></li>
      <li>Takaritó : <?=takarito?></li>
      <li>Munka jellege : <?=munkajellege?></li>
      <li>sorrend : <?=sorrend?></li>
      <li>Érkező vendégek száma : <?=vendegszam?></li>
      <li>Mikorra kell befejezni? : <?=befejezes?></li>
      <li> Mikor kezdhető a takarítás? : <?=erkezes?></li>
      <li>Komment : <?=komment?></li>
      <li>Cím : <?=cim?></li>
      <li>Emelet/ajtó infó : <?=emeletajto?></li>
      <li>Kapukód : <?=kapukod?></li>
      <li>Kulcsdoboz kód : <?=kulcsdoboz?></li>
    </UL>
  </body>
</html>


Modification points:

In your script, at for (var i = 1; i = lastline; i++) {, i is always the value of i = lastline, and the for loop is not finished.
I think that data in your script is a Class Range object. In this case, this cannot be used like data[i].
data[i, 1] might be data[i][0]? In the case of an array, the 1st index is 0. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation from your question. Does your Spreadsheet have the 1st header row? If it's so, the initial value is var i = 1.
In the case of GmailApp.sendEmail(adressee, takidatum + lakaskod + takarito, {htmlBody: htmlforemail});, the 3rd argument is required to be the text body. But, you use JSON object. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of "[object Object]" is in the received email's body.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
function myFunction() {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = wb.getSheetByName("automail");
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var takidatum = data[i][0];
    var sorrend = data[i][1];
    var takarito = data[i][2];
    var lakaskod = data[i][3];
    var vendegszam = data[i][4];
    var befejezes = data[i][5];
    var erkezes = data[i][6];
    var munkajellege = data[i][7];
    var komment = data[i][8];
    var cim = data[i][9];
    var emeletajto = data[i][10];
    var kapukod = data[i][11];
    var kulcsdoboz = data[i][12];
    var adressee = 'xy@gmail.com';
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email.html');
    htmlTemplate.takidatum = takidatum;
    htmlTemplate.sorrend = sorrend;
    htmlTemplate.takarito = takarito;
    htmlTemplate.lakaskod = lakaskod;
    htmlTemplate.vendegszam = vendegszam;
    htmlTemplate.befejezes = befejezes;
    htmlTemplate.erkezes = erkezes;
    htmlTemplate.munkajellege = munkajellege;
    htmlTemplate.komment = komment;
    htmlTemplate.cim = cim;
    htmlTemplate.emeletajto = emeletajto;
    htmlTemplate.kapukod = kapukod;
    htmlTemplate.kulcsdoboz = kulcsdoboz;
    var htmlforemail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(adressee, takidatum + lakaskod + takarito, "", { htmlBody: htmlforemail });
  }
}


In this modification, it supposes that the 1st header row exists in your Spreadsheet. If no 1st header row, please modify for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { to for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {.
Also, if data[i,1] in your script is the 2nd column, please modify data[i][0] to data[i][1]. And, please add 1 to each index after it.

References:

Class Range
Loops and iteration
Array
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)

